# this.graphClient.api("/me").get() returns GraphError code: null

Tags: azure, graph, authentication, botframework, chatbot

always gives 
GraphError {
  statusCode: -1,
  code: null,
  message: null,
  requestId: null,
  date: 2019-05-02T19:44:14.396Z,
  body: null }

while the previous step Sign In works

```
graphClient: Client;

async getMe() {
  return await this.graphClient
        .api('/me')
        .get().then((res) => {
            return res;
        });
}
```

Comment: Can you check again? There were several Azure outages in the last 1-2 hours that have largely been resolved. This may have impacted your attempts.

Comment: I am getting the same issue? Any updates?

Comment: Did you solve it ? ...